# Windows 2016 Answer file :: 'ad' is an undeclared prefix

Tags: windows, templates

I have developed a specialize file [unattend.xml] for Windows 2016 server from Windows System Image manager. This file is being use for sysprep for a template.

[image: Windows 2016 error screen capture]

It is throwing error message. Following are the error details:

```
Error opening C:\unattend.xml.
System.Xml.XmlException: 'ad' is an undeclared prefix. Line 28, position 4.
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.LookupNamespace(NodeData node)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ElementNamespaceLookup()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseAttributes()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElement()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElementContent()
   at System.Xml.XsdValidatingReader.Read()
   at Microsoft.ComponentStudio.ComponentPlatformInterface.Serializer.Validate(XmlSchema schema, String filename, ValidateCallBack additionalValidation, Object additionalParameter)
   at Microsoft.ComponentStudio.ComponentPlatformInterface.AnswerFile.DoLoad(Boolean useImagePathInAnswerFile)
   at Microsoft.ComponentStudio.MainForm.OnFileOpenUnattend(Command command)
```

Any help to resolve this?

Comment: can you post the contents of that file or at least the contents of line 28?